# Using Google maps API v3 how do I get LatLng with a given address?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

If a user inputs an address, I want to convert to the equivalent LatLng.

I've read the documentation, and I think I can use the Geocoder class to do this, but can't figure out how to implement it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There is a pretty good example on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

To shorten it up a little:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function codeAddress() {

    //In this case it gets the address from an element on the page, but obviously you  could just pass it to the method instead
    var address = document.getElementById( 'address' ).value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address' : address }, function( results, status ) {
        if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {

            //In this case it creates a marker, but you can get the lat and lng from the location.LatLng
            map.setCenter( results[0].geometry.location );
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                map     : map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            } );
        } else {
            alert( 'Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status );
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Don't we wish all documentation was as good as jQuery's. I have a hard time with some of Google's documentation.

Answer (score 33):

I don't think `location.LatLng` is working, however this works:

```
results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()
```

Found it while exploring [Get Lat Lon](http://www.getlatlon.com/) source code.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 23):

If you need to do this on the backend you can use the following URL structure:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[STREET_ADDRESS]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Sample PHP code using curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . rawurlencode($address) . '&key=' . $api_key);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close ($curl);

$obj = json_decode($json);
```

See additional [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for more details and expected [json response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#GeocodingResponses).

The docs provide sample output and will assist you in getting your own [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) in order to be able to make requests to the Google Maps Geocoding API.

Comment: Do you know what is the limit for this. I mean how many calls can I make in an hour or day ?

Comment: Free API limits are 2500 requests per 24 hour period, 5 requests per second ... see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Limits

Comment: Came here looking for this.  PHP users may want to use `$arr =  json_decode($json, true);` to access the data.