# setting marker for given address in google maps api with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am doing a web application using asp.net in which I want to take an address from a user in a textBox and show this address in a google maps api (that I implemented in my web application) by a marker (the tear drop shaped thing). So can someone please give me the code for doing that?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), it is pretty clear. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926836/using-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-get-latlng-with-a-given-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for placing a marker on the map by taking an address, then you need to look at the Geocoding service first. The example and description is well documented so I am not providing any code related to it.

[GEOCODING SERVICE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

The example provided above will take input from a HTML input element. Since your question is about taking input from an **Asp.net TextBox** this is what you can do-

Suppose you have-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_address" runat="server"> 
<asp:Button ID="btn_locate" runat="server" OnClientClick="codeAddress(); return false;">
```

instead of `var address = document.getElementById("address").value;` in the example,

write-

`var address= document.getElementById('<%=txt_address.ClientID%>').value;`

Remember the `return false` in the Button source since that will prevent a `postback` on submit.