# Showing street address in google maps API v2, need it in v3 now

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm using google maps api v2 below to show address in **var address** line on the map, and I want to have this in api v3. Does anyone know how to make this as google maps api v3?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
   var geocoder;
   var map;
   var address = "425 West 53rd St,New York,NY,";
   // On page load, call this function
   function load()
   {
      // Create new map object
      map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
      // Create new geocoding object
      geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
      // Retrieve location information, pass it to addToMap()
      geocoder.getLocations(address, addToMap);
   }
   // This function adds the point to the map
   function addToMap(response)
 {
   // Retrieve the object
   place = response.Placemark[0];
   // Retrieve the latitude and longitude
   point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
                       place.Point.coordinates[0]);
   // Center the map on this point
   map.setCenter(point, 15);
   // Create a marker
    marker = new GMarker(point);
    // Add the marker to map
    map.addOverlay(marker);
   }    //]]>
    </script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=xxxxxxxx" type="text/javascript"></script><div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at [the documentation for the v3 geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), and the ["simple" example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) it contains?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Google maps API v3 how do I get LatLng with a given address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926836/using-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-get-latlng-with-a-given-address)

Comment: I have looked at the documentations and examples for hours. They didn't help. All their examples are with input fields. I need to have address directly in the code like in my v2 example here. I'm not a programmer, that's why I asked for help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example from documentation, with your address instead of the "input field"

```
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address = "425 West 53rd St,New York,NY,";
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    codeAddress();
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GY3uu/3/)

Comment: Thank you for helping. I tried it and it didn't load the map at all. I made an example here. This is the original example from documentation http://jsfiddle.net/GY3uu/1/ and this is with your code http://jsfiddle.net/GY3uu/2/

Comment: Do you want it to match by your original code or by the documentation?  Notice the change of 'map-canvas' to 'map' which was the name of your div.

Comment: If I want to show multiple addresses on the map, what would I have to do here?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow for similar questions.  There are issues with quotas/rate limits for more than about 10 addresses.  For less than that, change codeAddress to take an argument, and pass in the different addresses.