# Google Geocoding API / Google earth

Tags: google-earth, google-geocoder

I hope you can help me with this weird problem I am having. First a bit of explanation.

I am coding a webapplication in php/javascript where you can create and save placemarks, which is then shown on a google earth globe on the website. In my application I have a search field that simply takes an address or city name.

Now this search functionality was working perfectly until about a week ago, and then it simply stopped working. First I thought I had done something, but when I go here: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/chinasyndrome/index.html and try to search for an address, its the same problem. Nothing happens.

My javascript that does the search looks like this:

geocoder = new google.maps.ClientGeocoder();

```
    function submitLocationMyWorld() {
      var address = el('searchByAddress').value;
      geocoder.getLatLng(
        address, 
        function(point) {
          if (point && geMyWorldMap3D != null)
            var la = geMyWorldMap3D.createLookAt('');
            la.set(point.y, point.x, 0, geMyWorldMap3D.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 
                   100, 0, 1000000);
            geMyWorldMap3D.getView().setAbstractView(la);
        }
      );
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thx

Answer (score 1):

I believe the geocoder comes from the [V2 version of the Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services).  That API has been deprecated for a while and was turned down recently.

I found [how to migrate to V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3), and, specific to your geocoding problem, [how to get the lat/lon using the V3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926836/using-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-get-latlng-with-a-given-address).

Comment: Great thx, I think this is exactly what I need, will have a look at it this weekend.

Comment: I still dont see how to make this work... Any Idea on what this line: geocoder = new google.maps.ClientGeocoder(); - would look like in V3, the rest looks to be the same.

Comment: Did you make all the changes necessary in the "how to migrate to V3" link (e.g., new API key, loading the API, etc.)?