# How to insert coordinates of Google map into javascript?

Tags: google-maps

So Im working on my project and the user is to enter an address after its been created in the database, i want it to show in a google map. I've found out the coordinates for the map through this link : 

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/650139/Finding-Co-ordinates-of-an-Address-in-ASP-NET-Csha

However this link shows the coordinates as a label where as i have a java script method as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(1.303895, 103.831941);
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

The script works fine if i enter the coordinates myself. I've tried parsing the latitude and longitude through a label and using document.getElementById() method however the map does not show.

Any clue how i can solve this ?

Comment: Why aren't you using the native [Google Maps Javascript API v3 geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Google maps API v3 how do I get LatLng with a given address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926836/using-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-get-latlng-with-a-given-address)