# How to update marker position from Here Maps API javascript

Tags: javascript, here-api

So I have a group and I want to update one marker position of this group from here map.

```
function addMarkerToGroup(group, coordinate, html) {
  var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
  // add custom data to the marker
  marker.setData(html);
  group.addObject(marker);
}


function addInfoBubble(map) {
  var group = new H.map.Group();

  map.addObject(group);

  // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
  group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
    // for all objects that it contains
    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
      // read custom data
      content: evt.target.getData()
    });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  }, false);

  addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:53.439, lng:-2.221},
    '<div><a href=\'http://www.mcfc.co.uk\' >Manchester City</a>' +
    '</div><div >City of Manchester Stadium<br>Capacity: 48,000</div>');

  addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:53.430, lng:-2.961},
    '<div ><a href=\'http://www.liverpoolfc.tv\' >Liverpool</a>' +
    '</div><div >Anfield<br>Capacity: 45,362</div>');

}
```

But how can I just update, here api have some watch or function like, updateMarkerPosition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use setGeometry method.

```
marker.setGeometry({lat:53.439, lng:-2.221});
```

Answer (score 1):

For Here Maps JS version 3 (2022):

```js
marker.setGeometry({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
map.setCenter({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want it to update? Considering the database or gelocalization? Or maybe you just want to be able to drag the marker where you want?

What you can do is put 2 input types with a lat and a long id. and use the document.getElementById() function, so anyone can type coordinates and it will update marker position. However if you want to use the adress, your question will be a duplicate of [Using Google maps API v3 how do I get LatLng with a given address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926836/using-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-get-latlng-with-a-given-address)

Comment: I want to update the marker position, so I have a marker set one position and I want to update this position on  map,
Somethings like this, I reveive a new lat and long coords and I want to update the position on map.

I dont want to drag the marker.

Comment: Thanks, but I have 2 problems, first I will receive coords data by Rest API, second I am using Here Maps API javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the setPosition() function on the marker to pass in a new position, like this:

```
marker.setPosition( {lat:50.430, lng:-2.961} );
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can I use setPosition inside my group? Because I am using this function addMarkerToGroup to show my markers on map.

Answer (score 0):

setPosition does not work for vector maps, this does however.

```
marker.setGeography({lat:50.430, lng:-2.961});
map.setCenter({lat:50.430, lng:-2.961});
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Comment: setPosition does not work for vector maps, use it, don't use it...